# Inconsistent Results From ARM Template Setting App Service Log Config

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

I am having the same issue that this SO user ran in to [ARM Template containing config settings for web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42831038/arm-template-containing-config-settings-for-web-app)
There was no resolution on that thread so I'm asking basically the same question again.  I have an ARM template that looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "logs",
  "type": "config",
  "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('AppServiceName'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "applicationLogs": {
      "azureBlobStorage": {
        "level": "Verbose",
        "sasUrl": "[concat('https://',parameters('StorageAccountName'),'.blob.core.windows.net/logs',parameters('SasToken'))]",
        "retentionInDays": null
      }
    },
    "httpLogs": {
      "azureBlobStorage": {
        "sasUrl": "[concat('https://',parameters('StorageAccountName'),'.blob.core.windows.net/logs',parameters('SasToken'))]",
        "retentionInDays": 360,
        "enabled": true
      }
    },
    "failedRequestsTracing": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "detailedErrorMessages": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

I'll run this once and in Resource Explorer the result is

```
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/.../providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/.../config/logs",
  "name": "logs",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
  "location": "East US",
  "properties": {
    "applicationLogs": {
      "fileSystem": {
        "level": "Off"
      },
      "azureTableStorage": {
        "level": "Off",
        "sasUrl": null
      },
      "azureBlobStorage": {
        "level": "Verbose",
        "sasUrl": "VALID_SAS_URL",
        "retentionInDays": null
      }
    },
    "httpLogs": {
      "fileSystem": {
        "retentionInMb": 35,
        "retentionInDays": null,
        "enabled": false
      },
      "azureBlobStorage": {
        "sasUrl": "VALID_SAS_URL",
        "retentionInDays": null,
        "enabled": true
      }
    },
    "failedRequestsTracing": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "detailedErrorMessages": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

Everything looks good in Resource Explorer and the portal.
Then I run the same template again and the result is:

```
{
"id": "/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/.../providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/.../config/logs",
"name": "logs",
"type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
"location": "East US",
"properties": {
  "applicationLogs": {
    "fileSystem": {
      "level": "Off"
    },
    "azureTableStorage": {
      "level": "Off",
      "sasUrl": null
    },
    "azureBlobStorage": {
      "level": "Verbose",
      "sasUrl": null,
      "retentionInDays": null
    }
  },
  "httpLogs": {
    "fileSystem": {
      "retentionInMb": 35,
      "retentionInDays": null,
      "enabled": true
    },
    "azureBlobStorage": {
      "sasUrl": null,
      "retentionInDays": null,
      "enabled": false
    }
  },
  "failedRequestsTracing": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "detailedErrorMessages": {
    "enabled": true
  }
}
```

I can run the same template a few more times and it's totally random whether the diagnostic logging gets enabled with the settings defined in the ARM template or not.

Comment: Does it work consistently if you set the same things via Resource Explorer? Also, is that the only thing in your ARM template, or it's part of a bigger thing?

Comment: This is part of a bigger thing but it is the only part that shows any inconsistency in the result when running the ARM template.  I don't generally use resource manager to make configuration changes but I just made a few updates without seeing anything similar to what I am experiencing using the ARM template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you also setting App Settings in your template? I think there may be an issue when they're used together. Try the following in your template:

- Set the App Settings first
- Then make the `config/log` dependent on the App Settings.

Comment: That was exactly it.  I added the dependsOn and it works reliably every time now.